# How to add scrollview in Table Layout?

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout

this is my first time using Scrollview and i want to make application with tablelayout 3x8 rows. The rows have same size height and width, and the table can scrolled vertically. how can i do this this in xml layout? thanks for your help

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Use TabLayout property look :app:tabMode="scrollable" may be help full..

Comment: thank you sir, it solve part of my problem @User6829548

Comment: Welcome @Denny..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one of the approach where you have to give your `TableRow` manually height so you can achieve this as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TableRow
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp">
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp">
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp">
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp">
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp">
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp">
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp">
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp">
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            </TableRow>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Another way of achieving the this you can use `GridView` or `RecyclerView`. `RecyclerView` is easiest way to achieve this. I hope its work for you. Thank you

Comment: Thank you sir, This help me alot.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `LinearLayout` from `ScrollView` and try, if it didn't work then use this

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" >
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F00"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F0F"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F00"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F0F"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F00"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F0F"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F00"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F0F"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F00"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F0F"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F00"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F0F"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, i try to remove my Linear Layout its not working. thank for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any layout other than `relative layout`. I don't know how it work, but it works.[for me at least]